# Openness/Closedness of the set of all ternary expansions with the same first n digits

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set, ternary-expansion

Let $x \in [0,1]$ and consider the set of all ternary expansions in the interval $[0,1]$ and in the Cantor Set whose first n digits are equal to those of ternary expansion of $x$.

I believe that for some $x = 0.a_1a_2...a_n...$, this set can be denoted as

$$
A_n = \{c = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{a_i}{3^i} + \sum^{\infty}_{j=n+1} \frac{b_j}{3^j}| b_j \in \{0,2\}\}
$$

where $a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ digit of the ternary expansion of $x$.

I would like to know whether this set is open and or closed under the standard topology of R, and whether a similar approach can be done for all expansions in general, not just ternary expansions.

Thanks

Comment: "Ternary" and "decimal" are contradictory. The first $n$ digits are equal to what? There's no apparent difference between $a_i$ and $b_j$, so it could be just one sum.

Comment: @aschepler by ternary expansion of a number i mean that numebr written in base-3 (using digits {0,1,2} only). Sorry I should have clarified, given the base 3 representation of an x in [0,1], I want A_n to be the set of all other base 3 numbers that have the same n first digits as x. I have edited the question to reflect this - sorry it was not clear at all.

Comment: I see. Then the set shouldn't specify $a_i \in$ since they're given beforehand. And $A_n$ is a plain closed interval.

Comment: @aschepler if A_n is an interval, does this imply that it is not a subset of the cantor set (as this set is codense and so has an empty interior)?